# How to determine drive type with a cross platform approach

Tags: c++

I am writing a cross platform app that should create files on certain events, now I have a problem, if my target be on a removable disk or a network drive I want to first create the file in a temporary folder on local hard drive and then move it to the target to avoid data loss in case of removal of the target path.

Now my question is how should I indicate type of the path in a cross platform approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "indicate"?

Comment: And why do you care? If the target path is removed during the write operation you will see some sort of error pop up when you flush the buffer.

Comment: Why don't you just do the copy from the temp directory anyway?

Comment: @Mellowcandle My service has a very high load and create many files, and in most cases target is on local hard drive, so if I always write to a temporary folder I will create extra work and disk activity for the service that is not very good for my service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be quite hard to achieve in a reliable and portable way. I'm sure all platforms have SOME way to find out if a drive is local or not, but I would have thought that a much more simple and reliable solution is to create a local temporary file whatever the base filesystem is.

Comment: My service has a really high load and always creating files in a local drive and then move them to target drive, create extra activity for service that is not required in most cases!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using QtMobility, you could use the [QSystemStorageInfo](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/qsystemstorageinfo.html) class.

Comment: I'm not using `Qt`, I'm using `std::iostream` and `boost::filesystem`

Comment: In that case it's going to be tough. AFAIK Boost.FileSystem is not up to the job. Either you have to write your own platform-specific code for each of the supported platforms, or adopt a simpler approach where you always write to the temporary file and only then move it into place.